# reactjs + styled-components with stateful component - my styles can't see props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Why can't props be seen when using a class/stateful component:

```
const StyledTitle = styled.h1 `
  color: ${props => (props.primary ? "royalblue" : "black")};
`;

class Title extends Component {
  render() {
    return <StyledTitle > {
      this.props.children
    } < /StyledTitle>;
  }
}

const App = () => ( 
  <div>
    <Title>Hi, Alice!</Title>
    <Title primary>Hi Bob, you are awesome!</Title>
  </div>
);
```

Here is Styled-Components' example:
[Adapting based on props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props)

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/oxqz3o30w5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the `primary` property to the styled component so it can render the logic depending on the `primary` property. Just add it in the component declaration.

```
const StyledTitle = styled.h1 `
    color: ${props => (props.primary ? "royalblue" : "black")};
`;

class Title extends Component {
  render() {
    return <StyledTitle primary={this.props.primary}> {
      this.props.children
    } < /StyledTitle>;
  }
}

const App = () => ( 
  <div>
    <Title>Hi, Alice!</Title>
    <Title primary>Hi Bob, you are awesome!</Title>
  </div>
);
```