# Is there any way i can style an element based on other elements state using styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I just started using styled-components and currently converting all my css into styled components in a project. But i am not sure how to achive some things and i could not find anything relevant in documentation too. I would like to know if the following problem is achievable using this approach in styled-components.
I have two checkboxes(radio input), if its checked i want to style a span element(Dot component in this case).

```
<div className="acc__type">
              <RadioInput type="radio" name="accType" id="dot-1" required />
              <RadioInput type="radio" name="accType" id="dot-2" required />
              <Category>
                  <AccTypeLabel for="dot-1">
                      <Dot></Dot>
                      <AccTypeTitle>Student</AccTypeTitle>
                  </AccTypeLabel>
                  <AccTypeLabel for="dot-2">
                      <Dot></Dot>
                      <AccTypeTitle>Staff</AccTypeTitle>
                  </AccTypeLabel>
              </Category>
</div>
```

here are my styled components

```
export const RadioInput = styled.input`
    display: none;
`;

export const Category = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 15px 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
`;

export const AccTypeLabel = styled.label`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
`;

export const AccTypeTitle = styled.div`
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
`;

export const Dot = styled.span`
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    
    //here iam trying to change this components styles based on <RadioInput/> components state. 
    #dot-1:checked & {
        border-color: #d9d9d9;
        background: #9b59b6;
    }
    
`;
```

in css i did this and it worked

```
#dot-1:checked ~ span,
#dot-2:checked ~ span {
  border-color: var(--sub-grey);
  background: var(--main-purple);
}
/* <Dot/> component was span here */
```

any help!

Comment: I think this would help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682517/reactjs-styled-components-with-stateful-component-my-styles-cant-see-props

Comment: Thank you, it did work. I was wondering if there was a way without using props?

Answer (score 0):

In Styled Components it's an ever so slightly different syntax, the reason is that it hashes the class names in a way that makes it difficult to target them. So this is how you do it in a way that ensures SC knows what's what:

```js
const dot1StyledComponent = styled.div`
  ...
`;

${ dot1StyledComponent }:checked ~ span {
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #9b59b6;
}
```